# Ruby Mechanize Find Form w/ No Name

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I'm pointing a Ruby solution at a form.  I have the page, but I don't know how to target the form because it has no name.

Here's the (beginning) form inside the page parsed by Mechanize:

```
     {forms
        #<Mechanize::Form
         {name nil}
         {method "GET"}
         {action
            "/app/ccc/srch/srch.do;jsessionid=00003bU0tdqSPfRfiG1f9n8g0gL:17e5e02re"}
         {fields
            [hidden:0x3ff0ed0d5f98 type: hidden name: lang value: eng]
            [hidden:0x3ff0ed0d5cdc type: hidden name: profileId value: ]
            [hidden:0x3ff0ed0d5818 type: hidden name: prtl value: 1]
```

I read on a python comment that I can use something that counts the forms by number (0 = first) but I tried using page.select_form(nr=0) and it didn't work.

Any advice appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Just found it.

```
CCCform = page.form()
```

Works like a charm.  I don't know how to get the second form on a potential page.

Cheers

Comment: that would be: page.forms[1]

Comment: @pguardiario Hi there.  Just tried page.forms(1) and I got this: `mechanize/page.rb:398:in 'forms': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)
 from mechanize.rb:27:in '<main>'`  What did work was `forms[0]`.  Thanks for posting that.

Comment: @pguardiario Yes, I found that out later after perusing methods.  Thanks for the reply.